# Set a eager loading function in my eloquent Object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

To avoid duplicate code, I would like to create a function eagerLoading() in my eloquent model. Here is my code:

Model **Product**:

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('active', 1);
}

public function eagerLoading($query)
{
    return $query->with([
        'owners',
        'attributes',
        'prices' => function ($query)
        {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
            $query->distinct('type');
        }
    ]);
}
```

**MyController**:

```
$products = Product::active()->eagerLoading()->paginate(100);
return $this->response->withPaginator($products, $this->productTransformer);
```

But when using this, I have this error : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::eagerLoading()`.

How should I use my function?

Comment: try renaming it to scopeEagerLoading, that would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `eagerLoading()` method is just another scope, like your `scopeActive()` method. In order to do what you want, you need to rename it to `scopeEagerLoading()`.

Right now, `Product::active()` is returning an Eloquent Query Builder. You are then trying to call `eagerLoading()` on that, and the method doesn't exist. By prefixing the method with `scope`, it tells the query builder to call the method on the Model for which it is querying.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:
"To define a scope, simply prefix an Eloquent model method with scope."

Check documentation at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes

So you need to rename your method to have "scope" at the beginning.

Change `public function eagerLoading($query)` to be `public function scopeEagerLoading($query)`